# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock on Docker

Tags: python-3.x, docker, flask, dockerfile

I have a flask application, locally and on Heroku server everything works fine, but when I run it with docker, I get the following error:

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:2.1.0-py3

RUN apt -qq -y update \
    && apt -qq -y upgrade

WORKDIR /socialworks-api
COPY . /socialworks-api

RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip

RUN apt -y install git

#for mysql
RUN apt install -y libmysqlclient-dev
RUN pip --no-cache-dir install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["/bin/bash", "./start.sh"]
```

Here is my start.sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash
export $(grep -v '^#' env/local.env | xargs)
source env/local.env
python app.py
```

This is the command I use to run my docker:

```
 docker run -it -p 5000:5000 flaskapp
```

Here is my docker ps:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
5e8484a7c613        flaskapp              "/bin/bash ./start.sh"   30 seconds ago      Up 29 seconds       0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp   eager_bell
```

Here are my docker logs:

```
 docker logs eager_bell
[nltk_data] Downloading package punkt to /root/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Unzipping tokenizers/punkt.zip.
2020-04-20 13:54:14.434376: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2020-04-20 13:54:14.457522: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 2394225000 Hz
2020-04-20 13:54:14.457923: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x4dbbd80 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-04-20 13:54:14.457952: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
test
(10) wsgi starting up on http://0.0.0.0:5000
(10) accepted ('172.17.0.1', 51222)
172.17.0.1 - - [20/Apr/2020 13:54:24] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 182 0.001607
172.17.0.1 - - [20/Apr/2020 13:54:25] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 397 0.001543
(10) accepted ('172.17.0.1', 51250)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2285, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 363, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 773, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 492, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 139, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 69, in __exit__
    exc_value, with_traceback=exc_tb,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 178, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 136, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 308, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 437, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 657, in __connect
    pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 69, in __exit__
    exc_value, with_traceback=exc_tb,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 178, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 652, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 114, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 490, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 84, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 179, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 161, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 272, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 38, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 161, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 272, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 38, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 468, in wrapper
    resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/views.py", line 89, in view
    return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 583, in dispatch_request
    resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/socialworks-api/controllers/image_controller.py", line 52, in get
    row_count = int(query.count())  # row count for keywords
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3669, in count
    return self.from_self(col).scalar()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3393, in scalar
    ret = self.one()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3360, in one
    ret = self.one_or_none()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3329, in one_or_none
    ret = list(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3405, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3427, in _execute_and_instances
    querycontext, self._connection_from_session, close_with_result=True
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3442, in _get_bind_args
    mapper=self._bind_mapper(), clause=querycontext.statement, **kw
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3420, in _connection_from_session
    conn = self.session.connection(**kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1133, in connection
    execution_options=execution_options,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1139, in _connection_for_bind
    engine, execution_options
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 432, in _connection_for_bind
    conn = bind._contextual_connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2251, in _contextual_connect
    self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, None),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2289, in _wrap_pool_connect
    e, dialect, self
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1555, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    sqlalchemy_exception, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 178, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2285, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 363, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 773, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 492, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 139, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 69, in __exit__
    exc_value, with_traceback=exc_tb,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 178, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 136, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 308, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 437, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 657, in __connect
    pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 69, in __exit__
    exc_value, with_traceback=exc_tb,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 178, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 652, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 114, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 490, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 84, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 179, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
172.17.0.1 - - [20/Apr/2020 13:54:28] "GET /images?keyword=sun HTTP/1.1" 500 112601 0.104478
172.17.0.1 - - [20/Apr/2020 13:54:28] "GET /images?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 6745 0.000661
(10) accepted ('172.17.0.1', 51254)
(10) accepted ('172.17.0.1', 51258)
172.17.0.1 - - [20/Apr/2020 13:54:28] "GET /images?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 200 88301 0.000740
172.17.0.1 - - [20/Apr/2020 13:54:28] "GET /images?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=debugger.js HTTP/1.1" 200 6555 0.000451
172.17.0.1 - - [20/Apr/2020 13:54:28] "GET /images?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 200 633 0.004653
```

My flask server runs successfully, but when I need to use mysql, it crashes with the error I have mentioned. I am not sure how to solve this issue. Also, I am new to docker.

Comment: Where did you configure the MySQL container? Or is it running locally (outside of Docker)?

Comment: It is running outside of Docker.

Comment: Also, in the future, I will need to connect to MySQL database on the server.

Comment: mysql connects to a socket if you specify `localhost`.  Specify 127.0.0.1 to get it over IP.

Comment: May I ask where should I specify it? In my env variables?

Comment: After I changed my HOST from local to 127.0.0.1 in my env file. I am now receiving the error: "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111). Is this the same thing?

Comment: I have just checked and it works on my database in Heroku server. Why does it not work with my local database?